# how to hash a "json" nested dictionary identically in Python and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, json, hash

What's the best way to consistently hash an object/dictionary that's limited to what JSON can represent, in both JavaScript and Python?  What about in many different languages?

Of course there are hash functions implemented consistently in many different languages that take a string, but to hash an object you have to convert it to a string representation first.

I want a hash function that will always return the same value for the same dictionary in any language, but the JSON spec doesn't guarantee anything about the order of keys in the serialized representation.

Do `json.dumps()` and `JSON.stringify()` behave identically?  How would you verify this?

If not, is there a serialization format with libraries in many languages (I'm practically interested in Python and JavaScript but also curious about all languages) that doesn't require any additional processing by the caller to produce consistent results?

Comment: They behave identically if you give them the right types of data (i.e. simple JavaScript objects and simple Python dicts, numbers, strings, and lists/arrays).

Comment: so sorting is part of the spec?

Comment: No, order shouldn’t have anything to do with it. Order is never guaranteed, and neither Python’s dicts nor JavaScript’s objects are ordered. What are you doing, comparing strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would split this into two problems.

1. How do you get the same serialized string in both JavaScript and Python?
2. Which byte array hash function should you use? It must be an established algorithm with identical implementations in both JavaScript and Python.

Use (1) to get two strings, then UTF8 encode, then use (2) to get hashes.

Since (2) is straightforward, I'll only address (1).

There are multiple facets to the problem of making sure the two JSON strings you generate are identical.

- You'll want to used unformatted JSON (no extraneous spaces, tabs, or newlines).
- null values must be treated identically. Some serializers will by default throw away a dictionary key-value pair if the value is null.
- Ordering of key-value pairs within a dictionary must be consistent.
- JSON number serialization should be consistent. For example, you can't have integer one serialize as `1`  on one side and `1.0` on the other. (This probably won't be as big of an issue however.)
- The string encoding should be the same for both.  JSON allows serialization to Unicode text, only mandating that `"` and `\` be backslash-escaped in JSON strings. Most serializers do more than necessary, however, and reduce almost all Unicode characters to the `\uXXXX` equivalent. See [json.org](http://json.org/) for the details on JSON string encoding. One way to remove all ambiguity is to only escape when absolutely necessary.

You'll want to make sure all of these are matched between JavaScript and Python. Most JSON serialization libraries I've used provide configuration hooks for all of the things I mention in the list above. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with the JavaScript or Python libraries.

Comment: in addition to `'"'` and `'\'`, you also must escape control characters such as `'\t'`, `'\n'` inside JSON strings otherwise it is not JSON. Another way to remove ambiguity is to make the output a pure ASCII e.g., in Python: `s = json.dumps(nested_dict, sort_keys=True, separators=(',',':'))`

Comment: wrong. Any json parser that accepts literal tab (09), newline (0a) or other control characters (inside string) is broken. See [rfc 4627](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627) and [JSON standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Sorry I was reading this page wrong: http://json.org/ It says "Any unicode character except " or \ or control character." I was missing "or control character".

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a well-defined language for representing the state of objects. The functions do not behave *identically*, but they do behave *equivalently*.

For instance:

```
json.dumps({'hello':'goodbye', 123: 456})
```

May produce either:

```
{"hello":"goodbye", "123": 456}
```

or

```
{"123": 456, "hello":"goodbye"}
```

And if you pass in the `indent` parameter then you get even more possibilities for different results.

Most languages if they do not already have a built-in way to handle JSON (e.g. Python & JS) then they'll have a 3rd party utility that is perfectly sufficient (see Newtonsoft JSON library for .NET)

Each language that I'm aware of will produce valid JSON, which means that it can be parsed by each other language that provides a JSON parser.

Comment: Well, actually, `json.dumps` will never produce either of those outputs. JSON’s keys are always quoted.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I might attempt a practical example.

In javascript I did:

```
import stringify from 'json-stable-stringify'
import sha256 from 'simple-sha256'

hash_str = sha256(stringify({'hello':'goodbye', '123': 456}))
// hash_str = 72804f4e0847a477ee69eae4fbf404b03a6c220bacf8d5df34c964985acd473f
```

`json-stable-stringify` guarantees a sorted json. `sha256` allows for nodejs / browser compatibility.

In python 3.8 I did:

```
import hashlib
import json

hash_str = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps({'hello':'goodbye', '123': 456}, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':')).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
# hash_str = 72804f4e0847a477ee69eae4fbf404b03a6c220bacf8d5df34c964985acd473f
```

I haven't yet done extensive testing but with the json objects I've tried, it has successfully matched.